# JUnit assertTrue exception

Tags: java, junit, assert

I am trying to use JUnit 4.0 to test if an application is returning the expected output on a boolean method.

Test is similar to following:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class ExampleTest{
    @Test
    public void somethingTest(){
         String [] words={"one","two","one","two","one","two","one","two"};
         for(String word:words){
             Example example = new Example(word);
             if(word.startsWith("o")){
                 assertTrue(example.isO());
             }else{
                 assertFalse(example.isO());
             }
         } 
    }
}
```

When I run the test, assertions that are correct work fine. Although when I get to an assertion that fails, exception is thrown and the tests stop returning this stack:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:92)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:43)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:54)
    at core.ExampleTest.somethingTest....
```

What I need is the tests to continue normally, and give me a number of passed and failing tests at the end. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a single test for each word. You can do this quite easily with [parameterized tests](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html).